# 'Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet',while connecting to cloud sql from GCE

Tags: mysql, google-compute-engine, google-cloud-sql

I have set up `google cloud sql` for my `GCE(google compute engine)` VM instance ,but I am unable to connect to the `google cloud sql` from VM instance .

In order to access the `google cloud sql` from the `GCE` ,I have requested for a `Ipv4` address for the cloud sql host . Then I have added the external IP of the `GCE` to the Allow networks under the authorization section of google cloud sql setting .

Tried to access the cloud sql from the `GCE` with the `Ipv4` address(as the host) and database user name and password using the following syntax

`mysql` `--host=<instance-ip-address> --user=<user-name> --password`

But getting the following  error in response.

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading
>   initial communication packet', system error: 0

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you haven't setup the allowed networks properly. Please double check your settings according to: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/access-control#appaccess

If you still have trouble, please contact cloud-sql@google.com with providing your instance name.